# Eigenvalues under linear transformation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let $X$ and $Y$ be square non-symmetric matrices of the same size. Assume that their eigenvalues are close in the sense that there exists a small $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $X$, there exists an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $Y$ such that $|\lambda-\mu|\le \varepsilon$.

Now, let $D$ be a diagonal matrix of bounded components. Can we say that eigenvalues of $DX$ and $DY$ are also close in the same sense (with $\varepsilon$ replaced by $C\varepsilon$ for some $C>0$)? References are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the order of quantifiers $\forall D\,\exists C\,\forall X, Y, \epsilon\,\ldots$?

Comment: In any case, $X$ and $Y$ can have the same eigenvalues, while $DX$ and $DY$ are not.

Comment: Wile @legon asked about $D$ being a bounded diagonal matrix, I think the question is more interesting if $D$ is a diagonal matrix of which all diagonal elements are in the interval $[a,b]$ such that $0<a<b$

Answer (score 6):

Consider the example $X=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a\\ &b\end{array}\right)$,  $Y=\left(\begin{array}{cc}b\\ &a\end{array}\right)$ and $D=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1\\ &0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: How about if $D$ is positive definite?